# Sublime-text 2: Control + P (Goto Anything) for all layout grid?

Tags: sublimetext

Currently, CTRL + P (Goto Anything) shortcut searching the file only in the current layout (grid). I use Grid:4, and want to search file no matter which grid the file is opened. Does anyone know how i can do this? or there's no way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not totally sure what you're trying to do, but if you want to 'search' in all open files (ie. find a sequence within all these files), you can do `ctrl+shift+F` (find anywhere) and then add 'Add Open Files' in the 'where' box and that will let you do it.

But if you want to 'goto' an open file in a different view/grid position, then `ctrl+P` ain't gonna cut it.. unless all the files are in the current project (projects are a good idea to use), then you can jump to any project file (although this will include non-open files, and exclude any open files not in the project.).

Or, if you just want to jump between open files in different views with keyboard commands you can use `Ctrl+PageUp/PageDown` to change tabs left to right in a view, or `Alt+[1,2,3,etc]` to jump to that number tab in a view, and `Ctrl+[1,2,3,4]` to change the focus between views.

Comment: Another nifty (but tricky) shortcut - you can right-click and use your mouse wheel to navigate between tabs